# Flask Routing URL with Empty Params

Tags: flask

How can I route a URL with empty params?

JFK-LAX for $100 works: `/username=Bob/flight_search/org=JFK&dst=LAX&price=100/`

JFK-(anywhere) for $100 throws 404 error: `/username=Bob/flight_search/org=JFK&dst=&price=100/`

The `dst=&` without any value seems to cause the problem.

```
@app.route('/username=<username>/flight_search/org=<org>&dst=<dst>&price=<price>/')
def flights(username, org, dst, price):
    flights = Flights.query.filter_by(org=org, dst=dst, price=price)
    return render_template('search_results.html', data=flights)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) to pass this data through, you should consider parsing URL params.  So the request URL would look more like:

```
example.com/flight_search/?username=foo&org=bar&dst=&price=123
```

The function `request.args.get()` will return `None` if no value is set.  With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35098028/2052575) you could then create the dictionary `filter_data` without these `None` values, and unpack them in the `filter_by` function:

```
@app.route('/flight_search/')
def flights():
    
    incoming_data = {}

    incoming_data['username'] = request.args.get('username')
    incoming_data['org'] = request.args.get('org')
    incoming_data['dst'] = request.args.get('dst')

    # This also supports defaults:
    incoming_data['price'] = request.args.get('price', default=100)

    filter_data = {key: value for (key, value) in incoming_data.items()
               if value}

    flights = Flights.query.filter_by(**filter_data)
    
    return render_template('search_results.html', data=flights)
```

Comment: Yep, this is perfect! Even answered the best way to unpack the args to the filter_by function. Thanks!