# How to with request.args.get() in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How to throw an exception if url query string spelling is wrong?

### Explanation :

this is the url to get particular user: 
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/t/user/?user_id=1`.
if endures will hit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/t/user/` it will give list of users.

### Question:

what if `user_id` spelling is wrong in query string ,like by mistake `use_id=1`, or instead of passing integer value, string value is passing to `user_id` I hope in this case I should return 404 page. I don't think internally `request.args.get()` will throw? if I have to handle this scenarios how to do?

### Some part of my code:

```py
page_index = request.args.get('index', 1, type=int)
max_item = request.args.get('max', 1, type=int)
userID = request.args.get('user_id', type=int)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could, create a custom error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
   return render_template('404.html', title = '404'), 404
```

Then use `abort` to raise this if the `user_id` param is not set:

```
from flask import abort

userID = request.args.get('user_id', type=int)

if not userID:
    abort(404)
```

Remember, `request.args.get` returns `None` as default, unless you give it the default argument:

```
foo = request.args.get('bar', default='Something')
```

**EDIT:** clarification.

If you specify the `type` argument to `request.args.get` this will return `None` if the value passed in the request is not of said type.

So for example:

```
incoming_data['user_id'] = request.args.get('user_id' , type=int)
print('Got: ', incoming_data['user_id'])
```

Will result in:

```
# request: /?user_id=1
Got: 1

# request: /?user_id=test
Got: None

# request: /?
Got: None
```

As per my other answer, linked in the comment, you can then build the filter accordingly:

```
filter_data = {key: value for (key, value) in incoming_data.items()
           if value}

result = MyModel.query.filter_by(**filter_data)
```

`filter_data` will only contain the key `user_id` if what was passed in the URL param was an integer.

Comment: Agree with your comment but in my case request query string parameter is optional . if it is not there i have to return all the user details .

Comment: @VVKkumar Possibly see my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275161/2052575) which deals with potentially not-present variables.

Comment: I have edited my explanation can you please go through once . The one you have answer its different scenarios , basically i meant how to validate query string ?

Comment: @VVKkumar See my edit, hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: Yes, i got it how to work around it. Thanks a lot man.